# setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback not work with my editText :(

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, custom-controls

On my editText, when i do setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {}) then the Callback is never called :( i think everything on the edittext is well configured, i do

- settextIsSelectable(true);
- setfocusable(true);
- setfocusableInTouchMode(true);
- setlongClickable(true);

What in my editText can forbid the callback ? how to build custom context menu for my edittext ?

This is my code :

```
this.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        Log.e("onPrepareActionMode","onPrepareActionMode");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        Log.e("onCreateActionMode","onCreateActionMode");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        Log.e("onDestroyActionMode","onDestroyActionMode");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    Log.e("onActionItemClicked","onActionItemClicked");
    return true;
    }

});
```